# Expand location only for specific file types

Tags: nginx

I've a NGINX Reverse Proxy setup for my NodeJS app.

My location block looks basically like this

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  gzip on;
  gzip_static on;

  expires 86400;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

No I want to *expand* this location for specific file types (js,css,png, ..) with

```
expires: max;
```

In case I couldn't overwrite the initial `expires` header I would be fine leaving it in the location block.

---

My static files are all located in `/static/..` and I just could setup a second location block, but this would generate some overhead (setting the `proxy_pass` again etc). So I'm curious if I can expand blocks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a second location block as `proxy_pass` directives (all handlers, for that matter, see [this post](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,243488,243493#msg-243493)) aren't inherited by nested location blocks.

If you want to simplify your configuration without copy-and-pasting your other configuration, consider an [`include`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) directive and put the common aspects of your location block into an external file.

It is technically possible that you could get away with just one location block by adding an `if` statement like:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^/static) {
    expires max;
}
```

but as per the Nginx wiki's [If is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) page, you'll want to test this and *very* carefully.  This also involves more of an overhead by invoking the regex engine; the better option is two location blocks.